# tcolorbox in a footnote

Tags: listings, footnotes, tcolorbox, matlab-prettifier

I want to put a tcolorbox (or actually a lstlisting defined by `\newtcblisting` ) into a footnote. Thus, something like the following (which does not compile)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\newtcblisting[]{tlisting}[1][]{
    listing only,
    listing options={
        style=Matlab-editor,
    }
}

\begin{document}

Some Text\footnote{Some Text: %
\begin{tlisting}
code
\end{tlisting}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should probably not assume that anything listings like can be used inside the arguments for other macros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a `tcolorbox` --with Matlab code inside-- in a footnote.

For listing the code I found two options. See the answers to [typeset matlab code in a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75116/what-can-i-use-to-typeset-matlab-code-in-my-document)

In both cases you can directly include an external m-file from somewhere  using `\lstinputlisting{/SOMEPATH/FILENAME.M}`.

**(1)** Using the `M-code LaTeX Package` from [download the package m-code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package)

[image: ag1]

with this code (see  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78393/161015)

```
\documentclass{article}


%% See  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78393/161015
%% https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}

% default font
\def\lstbasicfont{\sffamily\footnotesize}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sample.m}
for i = 1:3
    if i >= 5 && a ~= b       % literate programming replacement
        disp('cool');           % comment with some §\mcommentfont\LaTeX in it: $\mcommentfont\pi x^2$§
    end
    [:,ind] = max(vec);
    x_last = x(1,end) - 1;
    v(end);
    really really long really really long really really long really really long really really long line % blaaaaaaaa
    ylabel('Voltage (µV)');
end
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

See as example\footnote{mcode: %
        \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!2]   
            \lstinputlisting{sample.m}%
        \end{tcolorbox}
    }
    
\end{document}
```

**(2)** Using the package `matlab-prettifier`:

[image: bg2]

This is the code: (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/161015)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

%% See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/161015
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{sample.m}
    for i = 1:3
        if i >= 5 && a ~= b       % literate programming replacement
            disp('cool');           % comment with some §\mcommentfont\LaTeX in it: $\mcommentfont\pi x^2$§
        end
    [:,ind] = max(vec);
        x_last = x(1,end) - 1;
        v(end);
        really really long really really long really really long really really long really really long line % blaaaaaaaa
        ylabel('Voltage (µV)');
    end
\end{filecontents*}

\let\ph\mlplaceholder
\lstMakeShortInline"

\lstset{
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle         = \mlttfamily,
    escapechar         = ",
    mlshowsectionrules = true,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
}

\begin{document}

See as example\footnote{matlab-prettifier: %
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=blue!2,boxsep=20pt,top=-10pt,bottom=-15pt]    
        \lstinputlisting{sample.m}%
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\end{document}
```

Notice the different outputs to    `% comment with some §\mcommentfont\LaTeX in it: $\mcommentfont\pi x^2$§` (line #3) and to
`Voltage (µV)` (line #9)